# Use Windows Rust Crate and EvtSubscribe to listen to windows events

Tags: windows, rust

I am trying to listen to windows events using the code below and it will work intermittently between runs.

I will get `{ code: 15000, kind: Uncategorized, message: "The specified channel path is invalid." } :: Error { code: HRESULT(0x80073A98), message: "The specified channel path is invalid." }` or `{ code: 15007, kind: Uncategorized, message: "The specified channel could not be found." } :: Error { code: HRESULT(0x80073A9F), message: "The specified channel could not be found." }` every other run, especially using CTRL+C to exit the application, how should I force a cleanup of the handler (assuming that's the issue) between runs?

```rust
use std::ffi::{CString, OsString};
use std::io::Error;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use windows::core::PCWSTR;
use windows::Win32::System::EventLog::*;

fn main() {
    let channel = to_wchar("Application");
    let query = to_wchar("*");

    // Open a subscription to the event log
    let subscription = unsafe {
        EvtSubscribe(
            None,
            None,
            channel,
            query,
            None,
            None,
            Some(event_callback),
            EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord.0, // EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord.0,
        )
    };

    let error = Error::last_os_error();
    println!("Seen: {:?}", error);

    if subscription.is_err() {
        let sub_error = subscription.err().unwrap();
        println!(
            "Failed to subscribe to event log: {:?} :: {:?}",
            error, sub_error
        );
        return;
    }

    loop {
        // Sleep for 10 milliseconds
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
    }

    // Clean up the subscription
    unsafe { EvtClose(subscription.unwrap()) };
}

unsafe extern "system" fn event_callback(
    _: EVT_SUBSCRIBE_NOTIFY_ACTION,
    _: *const std::ffi::c_void,
    event_handle: EVT_HANDLE,
) -> u32 {
    println!("CALLBACK!");
    0
}

fn to_wchar(str: &str) -> PCWSTR {
    // Convert the OsString to a wide string (UTF-16)
    let mut raw_mut_str = str.encode_utf16().chain(Some(0)).collect::<Vec<u16>>();
    let str_ptr = raw_mut_str.as_mut_slice().as_mut_ptr();

    // winnt::LPWSTR::from(str_ptr)
    PCWSTR::from_raw(str_ptr)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `to_wchar` function is creating a `PCWSTR` around a pointer that is no longer pointing to the `raw_mut_str` vector when the function returns. (The vector goes out-of-scope and its backing memory de-allocated.) This dangling pointer is then passed to the Win32 API resulting in undefined behavior (UB).

The `windows` crate has a helper macro `w!` for creating null-terminated wide string constants. Here's an example:

```rust
use windows::w;

let subscription = unsafe {
    EvtSubscribe(
        None,
        None,
        w!("Application"),
        w!("*"),
        None,
        None,
        Some(event_callback),
        EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord.0
    )
};
```

Comment: Heya - I did wind up solving this by fixing the `to_wchar` implementation but I didn't realize that `w!` was a macro that I could use for that. Thanks for the answer! I think I'll try that instead :) Do you know if there's a reverse operation as well for `PCWSTR`?

Comment: Not sure I'm following. What are the source and target types you're looking for in this scenario? (Slight tangent: There are also `s!` and `h!` for compile-time ANSI and HSTRING strings respectively.)